# Postgres как ограничить интервал внесенных данных

Tags: sql, postgresql

Получаю данные с датчика. Иногда он сбоит и шлет откровенный бред. Как мне при `insert` проверять число в диапазоне или нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я может чего-то не знаю. Но вроде же это?

```
ALTER TABLE table  ADD CONSTRAINT "table_chk" CHECK (value > 0 and value < 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте триггер before insert на таблицу, в которую данные вносите. В триггерной функции проверяйте на здоровье всё что хотите. [Man в помощь](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Если данные корректны - верните из триггерной функции NEW, иначе NULL.

Comment: так ? DECLARE tank real;

 BEGIN tank = NEW."F_ConvertedValue";

 IF (tank > 0
     AND tank < 5000) RETURN NEW;

ELSE RETURN NULL;

 END IF;

 EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN RAISE NOTICE 'SQLSTATE: %',
                                         SQLSTATE;

 RAISE;

 END;

Comment: Тело триггерной функции похоже на правду. Только с exception'ом ваш замысел не понял.

Comment: да я где то подсмотрел. сча юзаю. вродь как текст ошибки выкинуть должна